# React - Parsing error: Unexpected character

Tags: reactjs, parsing

I'm working on a project and I got this error, someone know why? Thank you !

```
./src/config/configStore.js
  Line 5:  Parsing error: Unexpected character '​'

  3 | import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
> 5 | ​import monitorReducersEnhancer from '../enhancers/monitorReducer';
    | ^
  7 | import loggerMiddleware from '../middleware/logger';
  8 | import rootReducer from '../Reducers/index';
```

Comment: What's on line 4?

Comment: What does the `../enhancers/monitorReducer` file look like? This looks like an issue with the module that is being exported from that file.

Comment: hello, you can check the file in the redux doc : https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuringyourstore in the "Extending Redux functionality" part @ChaseDeAnda

Comment: @FrankerZ i tried to eslint disable the line 5, but i removed it from the topic